# How to place the first character of a string in the last position of the string in Java?

Tags: java, string, methods, char

Beginner Java programmer. For a school assignment, I need to write a program which does some calculations with a number and that same number if it's first member/character has been placed in the last position (e.g. 2567 and 5672). I decided to go about it by converting the numbers to strings, get the first character of each string and place it on the back to get the second number I need. Although I assume that's a very stupid question, I can't seem to find a method for manipulating strings in the way I need, so how do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Since I posted the code in whole, I'll also include what the entire problem consists of:
Calculating whether the difference between A and B (being 2567 and 5672 for example) is greater than 5000. If it is - A should be printed, then the same for all numbers A within the range 10 - 10000 and B being A with it's first character as last.

```
public class new1 {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        int bot = 10;
        int top = 10000;
        int difference = 5000;
        int a, b, c;
        a = bot;

        while (a<10000) {
            String str1 = String.valueOf(a);
            // my question comes at about this point
            String str2 = "10"; // this line is just as an example; my idea is to then convert back to int and store in b for calculation;
            b = Integer.parseInt(str2);

            c = a - b;

            if (c > difference)
                System.out.println(c);
            else
                a++;
        }
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

Comment: are you always going to get 4 digit numbers?

Comment: Also, when posting questions here, it's usual to show what work you have attempted.  Most folks here will refuse to be treated as a code-it-for-you service and won't help.  Please include your code, working or not.

Comment: @DevZer0 The numbers will be in a range between 10 and 10000.

Comment: Post your work that you did to try and solve the problem.

Comment: "*I can't seem to find a method for manipulating strings in the way I need*" - Your needs can probably be met by utilizing multiple methods of `String` (such as `startsWith` or `charAt`). You should view the [JavaDocs for String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to learn of the methods which `String` exposes.

Comment: @markspace Posted. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Jason just did.

Comment: i am wondering if your professor would like you to solve this purely with Maths or if String manipulation is allowed. It's possible to solve with a purely mathematical approach as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if it's first member/character has been placed in the last position (e.g. 2567 and 5672).`

I'm not sure I understand, but the first character is `charAt(0)` and the last one will be `charAt(str.length()-1)`.

OK I re-read your example and I think I see a different interpretation.  You can remove characters too with `substring()` and add them again with concatenation, which is easiest to do with `+`.

```
while (a<10000) {
    String str1 = String.valueOf(a);
    // problem: move first char to last;
    String str2 = "10"; // example; convert to int and store in b for calculation;

    // this takes the first character of str1 and moves it to 
    // end of str2.

    // 1. Make a copy first
    char first = str1.charAt(0);
    // 2. Now remove the character and assign to str2
    str2 = str1.substring(1);
    // 3. Place the saved copy at the end
    str2 = str2 + first;

    b = Integer.parseInt(str2);

    c = a - b;

    if (c > difference)
        System.out.println(c);
    else
        a++;
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Take input as a string.
2. Take all the chars in this string except 1st pos.
3. append the chars at 1st place into above string

   `String str = String.valueOf(2567);
    System.out.println(str.substring(1)+str.substring(0,1));`